# constraint error on INPUT command

Tags: mysql, database, constraints

I am doing some MySQL coding but getting a few errors when entering data.

Can you have a look at my code and just see if I am missing something?

```
CREATE DATABASE test1

USE test1

CREATE TABLE subject1 (
    s1_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    field1 VARCHAR(20),
    field2 VARCHAR(30),
    field3 CHAR(10),
    field4 VARCHAR(30),
    PRIMARY KEY (s1_id)
);

CREATE TABLE subject2 (
    s2_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    s2_s1_id INT NOT NULL,
    field5 VARCHAR(20),
    field6 DATE,
    field7 DATE,
    Field8 INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (s2_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (s2_s1_id) REFERENCES subject1 (s1_id)
);
```

I keep getting a constraint error on the `s2_s1_id` field.

```
INPUT INTO subject2 (
    `s2_s1_id`,
    `field5`,
    `field6`,
    `field7`,
    `field8`
)
VALUES (
    '1',
    ' SOLOTION 2.5',
    '2015-10-10 10:00:00',
    '2015-10-11 10:30:00','25'
);
```

> Mysql error 1452 - cannot add or update a child row: a foreign constraint fails.

Any thoughts?  It's a DB for my own personal use to track my numbers for dialysis.

Comment: Do you mean **con**straint error?

Comment: Lol yes.  My mistake.

Comment: Do you get the error when you just create the table, or when you try to add rows to the tables? I don't get an error here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b71f7

Comment: Please post the exact error you get.

Comment: Are you trying to add rows to `subject2` before you add the rows to `subject1` that they reference?

Comment: No.  I add records to table 1 first.

Comment: Please show what you're doing and the error message.

Comment: Sounds like you're not copying the value of the new `s1_id` into `s2_s1_id` properly. But it's impossible to tell what you're doing wrong without seeing the code.

Comment: Mysql error 1452 - cannot add or update a child row: a foreign constraint fails.

Comment: Please update the question with the code that's inserting the rows.

Comment: How else do you expect us to figure out what you're doing wrong?

Comment: INPUT INTO subject2 (`s2_s1_id`,`feild5`,`field6`,`field7`,`field8`) VALUES ('1','SOLOTION 2.5','2015-10-10 10:00:00','2015-10-11 10:30:00','25');

Comment: You see the "edit" link below the question? Use it to update the question.